# Combining material from various different licences under CC BY-NC-SA 4.0 license

Tags: mit, cc-by-nc-sa

If I use the material (GLSL code) in a project in which I use MIT licensed material with Resolume-Wire (an object-oriented application based on nodes) in the ISF (GLSL code) import element there, add additional Wire nodes/functions or two such ISF elements (one with MIT and another with CC BY-NC-SA license) or just add more functions from Wire. Compile this result to create a closed Resolume Arena plugin.

So various such plugins created in a total project (about 65) and this project total is under a CC BY-NC-SA 4.0 license published, is this so legal? Can I get from the MIT license holders, because of the so "co-used" material problems?

I have to add that I

1. include a listing of the plugins in table form with credits for the elements used in a PDF attached to the project. In this PDF I explicitly point out that the plugins are only to be used for Resolume-Arena and that they contain foreign material with MIT as well as CC and LYGIA licenses, and if someone is interested in the original code of these elements please go to the originals via the links in the PDF, inform yourself about the terms of use and if necessary download the foreign material there.
2. No one can't my result, i.e. the plugins, be viewed in of such a way that the code used becomes visible again, when the plugins are passed on (is compiled)? Thus, the MIT or LYGIA licensed co-used material cannot be individually copied, freely distributed or used as such. After the compilation in Wire, the plugin is closed and the original material can (possibly) only be uncovered as illegally copied.
   My CC BY-NC-SA 4.0 license offers increased protection for the authors of the original elements used with MIT or LYGIA etc. licenses.
3. And I am also of the opinion that my process of creating, in particular the functional expansion and mixing, has created something new, where I, as its author, and I'am free to choose which license I use, and I also refer to the integrated elements and their licenses, please pay attention if you do at the place where I bought the material myself would also like to use it.

I want to give a gift to the Resolume Arena users, contribute to this community and not cause or create problems or trouble.

Who can please give me answers and links to my protection

Comment: Note that the CC-NC variants are not open source licenses so this question may be off-topic here; we give _some_ latitude to -NC but not an infinite amount.

Comment: THX i'am nubi hear and real SRY i was shure it is open source (CC),
but with exuse the MIT is open source and so meaby the tag ist ok

Comment: And to GLSL with witch is ISFs made, is Part of OpenGL, so put my not to the BSD side -------
And Sry my english is weri pur

Comment: Dear Philip Kendall I'm not very familiar with things like this on the internet in general. Am just a multimedia & video artist. Can you then help me where to place my question or which member to contact.
Please something constructive.
LG bennoH.

Comment: You probably need to talk to an actual lawyer.

Comment: What you can and cannot do with third-party material depends on the exact text of the licenses involved. The LYGIA license that you reference is unknown to me. Can you post a link to the license text (or a project using the license)?

Comment: In point two above, are you saying that you specifically want users not to be able to access the source code of plugins, even when you got the code that goes into them under the MIT licence?  And that you want the result to be distributed under CC BY-NC?

Comment: I am Videoartist without mony for satch things

Comment: THX a lot Rohit Gupta for editing my question-Text and formating.  Super work THX with LG

Comment: To the LIGIA i hafe to say, wen i DL this Material it was in Git-hub declaret as MIT. Then i E-Mail the owner to THX him and inform. He send my back that he chanch the MIT to LYGIA https://github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/lygia/#license.  Bud afterways it mast my not reell intrest, i think so. And now i mast do my reell creativ work. Hoppe somone helps me hear. Sry for my misserable english.

Comment: Dear MadHatter, after i send the Remix out thru a compile Funktion to geht the Result, a Plugin for Resolume-Arena (proprietary Soft for Videoartist and VJs) i can do that this ist the normal proces by compiling, that is afterworts not to se in the Plugincode, so to never can se in also not to the MIT or other Code-Material.

Comment: I think wath i do is in Copyrighting a "Remix" out of free Material, and so i am free to juse a License, but i was fair and use the strongest with the moast seavty for the Originals withused Material.    Bud i am not a loyer or jurist and all this rightstuff ist enormus complex, to complex for Artistcal use. CC ist clear and easy to Handel and so a ok Thing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about using third-party MIT-licensed content to create a piece of work that will in turn be licensed under CC BY-NC, and that's off-topic for this site.